# knit() doesn't create .tex file with necessary preamble

Tags: knitr, rstudio

I have a question about creating .tex from .Rnw using knitr in Rstudio.

I have a test.Rnw file while looks like the following:

```
\input{report_preamble_en.tex}

\title{test}
\author{author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

test
<<cache=TRUE>>=
a = 1
@

\end{document}
```

Then in Rstudio, I create a test.tex file by calling the following R function:

```
knit('test.Rnw')
```

The following is the content of the test.tex file:

```
\input{report_preamble_en.tex}

\title{test}
\author{author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

test
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{alltt}
\hlstd{a} \hlkwb{=} \hlnum{1}
\end{alltt}
\end{kframe}
\end{knitrout}

\end{document}
```

My question is that why this test.tex file doesn't include the necessary preamble shown below?

```
%\documentclass{article}\usepackage[]{graphicx}\usepackage[]{color}
%% maxwidth is the original width if it is less than linewidth
%% otherwise use linewidth (to make sure the graphics do not exceed the margin)
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{ %
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\definecolor{fgcolor}{rgb}{0.345, 0.345, 0.345}
\newcommand{\hlnum}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.686,0.059,0.569}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstr}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.192,0.494,0.8}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlcom}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.678,0.584,0.686}{\textit{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlopt}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.345,0.345,0.345}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwa}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.161,0.373,0.58}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwb}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.353,0.396}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.333,0.667,0.333}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.737,0.353,0.396}{\textbf{#1}}}%

\usepackage{framed}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{kframe}{%
 \def\at@end@of@kframe{}%
 \ifinner\ifhmode%
  \def\at@end@of@kframe{\end{minipage}}%
  \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}%
 \fi\fi%
 \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin \hskip-\fboxsep
 \colorbox{shadecolor}{##1}\hskip-\fboxsep
     % There is no \\@totalrightmargin, so:
     \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
 \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
   \@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
   \@setminipage}}%
 {\par\unskip\endMakeFramed%
 \at@end@of@kframe}
\makeatother

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.97, .97, .97}
\definecolor{messagecolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{warningcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 1}
\definecolor{errorcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}
\newenvironment{knitrout}{}{} % an empty environment to be redefined in TeX

\usepackage{alltt}
```

This happens today for the first time. Usually, the above preamble codes would appear in the test.tex file, between `\input{report_preamble_en.tex}` and `\title{test}`.

In Rstuido, I use xelatex.

I am not sure if this is relevant but I updated my Mac OS to Yosemite and reinstalled Rstudio to solve the problem that Tex is not found.

Comment: You need to include a `\documentlcass{}` in your `.Rnw` file, otherwise `knitr` doesn't know where to put its preamble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`knit()` relies on `knit_patterns` to insert things into a document as it is being processed. The default patterns that `knitr` relies on are defined in the list `all_patterns`, which you can view by just typing `all_patterns` into an R session (assuming you have loaded `knitr`).

If you do this, you will see the following somewhere in the output.

```r
$tex$header.begin
[1] "(^|\n)[^%]*\\s*\\\\documentclass[^}]+\\}"
```

In short, this is needed so that `knitr` knows where to put its default preamble for a `.tex` file.

To quote from [Yihui's website for `knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/patterns):

> `header.begin`: the pattern to find out where the document header begins; this is used to insert some header information into the output document (e.g. commands in the preamble in LaTeX, or CSS styles in HTML)

So, in order to get the correct output in `test.tex`, you need to make sure that your `.Rnw` file has a declared `\documentclass{}` in it.

Of course, you can change this if you want to by using `knit_patterns$set()`.

So if you want to always use `\input{report_preamble_en.tex}` as your `$tex$header.begin`, then you can do the following to `knit()` the file:

```r
library(knitr)
knit_patterns$set(header.begin = "(^|\n)[^%]*\\s*\\\\input\\{report_preamble_en.tex+\\}")
knit('test.Rnw')
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. But there is a typo in '\documentlcass{}'. I removed `\documentclass[11pt]{article}` from my _report_preamble_en.tex_ preamble input file and added it to the .Rnw file. Does this mean that if I use knitr package, I cannot define my documentclass in a separate preamble file? I am asking because usually I use the same preamble for all pdf I write and I like keeping them in a separate file.

Comment: @PanChao Thanks for pointing out the typo. I've fixed it. I imagine that there is probably a way to change the value of `$tex$header.begin` to search for `\input{report_preamble_en.tex}` rather than for a `\documentclass{...}`, but I'm not particularly familiar with the `knitr` internals. The place to start looking would be the [manual for `knitr` that's on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/knitr.pdf), though:

Comment: @PanChao See my updated answer.